# run out usage with timeframes

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

If I'm waiting for something happen and I know that it will happen in 3 months. Can I say "When 3 months run out I'll do it". Is that grammatically correct?

Comment: It doesn't sound natural. Might be you mean "I will do it within the next 3 months".

Comment: I mean that I will start doing something after 3 months actually. For example: I'll be able to request comments from the authorities when 3 months have passed. I'm not sure if this phrase sounds natural to you.

Comment: Whilst it's true we say things like ***time is running out***, your usage is not at all idiomatic. About the only context where I can imagine *[some specified time duration] running out* is where that specific duration has already been identified as contextually relevant, in which case it *just about* works if an article is included: *It only comes with a three-month guarantee, but when **the** three months run out you can still get it repaired for a nominal fee.* But it's not very good even there, to my ear.

Comment: That's clearer. I think I'd say "I will do it in three months' time (and not before)". Although, personally, I'd specify an actual month for the task to start because I find the inanimate possessive apostrophe in that sentence confusing.

Comment: No, that's not correct and if it was, I suggest you should take it either to English Language Learners or even to a site dealing with writing style.